# jQuery&php fire function when page is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have a php page with jQuery, with range sliders.
When the sliders are changed the jQuery code sums the values.

I also want this code to be fired when the page is loaded. But it doesn't happen when I trigger the function inside $(window).load(function() {}); or directly in $(document).ready(function() {});.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).load(function() {
                countSilders();
            });
            function countSliders(){
                var SliderValue = parseInt($("#slider0").val())+parseInt($("#slider1").val())+parseInt($("#slider2").val());
                if (SliderValue==10)
                    $("#submit_next").button("enable");
                else
                    $("#submit_next").button("disable");
                $("#lblsum_scores").text(SliderValue+"/10");
            }
            $(document).on("change","#sliders", function(){
                countSliders();
            });
        });
```

Comment: You have 6 questions you have left unanswered, and you don't even thank anyone for helping. Might consider doing so?

Comment: @s.lenders. Please scroll down and read.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// First define your function
function countSliders() {
    var SliderValue = parseInt($("#slider0").val()) + parseInt($("#slider1").val()) + parseInt($("#slider2").val());
    if (SliderValue == 10) $("#submit_next").button("enable");
    else $("#submit_next").button("disable");
    $("#lblsum_scores").text(SliderValue + "/10");
}

// Run on ready, don't use ready and then on load, that will never happen
// And i changed the on() to change() 
$(document).ready(function(){
    countSilders();
    $("#sliders").change(function(){
        countSliders();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
function countSliders(){
   ...
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    countSilders(); // fire it on load

    // bind it to sliders
    $(document).on("change","#sliders", function(){
        countSliders();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx. Defining the slider-function outside document.ready works when loading the page for the first time. But after submitting the form, it should work again and then it doesn't (only after hitting the sliders)